# Remove specific duplicates in ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, set, duplicates, hashset

How can I remove duplicates in an ArrayList in Java, except for specific elements?
For instance if I have an ArrayList with

```
"a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "a", "b", "b", "d", "c"
```

I only want to remove the duplicates for `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"` and I also need to maintain the order of the elements. The duplicates of `"d"` cannot be removed.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to maintain 2 lists:

One which is the actual list while the other is removeDuplicated list which tells your program  which entries to keep unique.

Also, you can maintiain the order by either using a LinkedList or a ArrayList.

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Answer (score 0):

I would create another array without duplicates.

Create another array(list2) and add elements from source array(list1) if list2 does not contain the same element except for "d".

```
ArrayList<String> list1;
ArrayList<String> list2;

for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++) {
    String element = list1.get(i);
    if((!element.equals("d")) && (!list2.contains(element))) {
        list2.add(element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to write code if this is a homework exercise for you.

Do the following.

1. Define a `HashSet` of not allowed items `('a','b','c')` and an empty `HashSet` called elimination set.
2. Iterate through the `ArrayList`.
3. Test the item against elimination `HashSet` and remove the item from `ArrayList` if the item is in elimination set.
4. Test the item against not allowed `HashSet` and add the item to elimination `HashSet` if the item is in not allowed set.

Time complexity is *O(n)* where *n* is length of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

I would create 2 arrayList. One with the values and one with the values you want to remove. Simply do a removal with the list of the values you no longer want.

```
public class SOTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     String [] strAr = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "a", "b", "b", "d", "c"};
     String [] removeAr = {"a", "b"};

     ArrayList<String> arList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(strAr));
     ArrayList<String> removeList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(removeAr));
     arList.removeAll(removeList);

     for(String s : arList)
         System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```